# Dynamically change text from JS file in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

My app init after some async changes (my `main.js`):

```
(async function () {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('/config.json');
    let config = await response.json();
    window.appConfig = config;
    appInit();
  } catch (error) {
    alert('appConfig not found!')
    window.stop();
  }
})();
```

and inside `appInit()` i use

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  i18n,
  store
})
```

But i have some texts inside `.js` file and now i use like this:

```
export default { super_name: 'Super name' }
```

My question: how can i use inside `.js` file dynamic `$i18n` texts? I can't export `new Vue`, because it is inside function `appInit()`

I tried almost everything